# PHP Curl Bad Request JSON - проблема в сообщение

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

есть массив  дата, который передается для отправки через curl  в фукцнию

```
$arData = [
  "NAME" => 'Название конференции',
  "CODE" => "",
  "START" => '18.04.19 11:11:10',
];
telegramNotificationSend($id, $typeNotification, $arData);
```

в функции отправки есть код формирующий сообщение

```
$textNotification = " Конференция " . $arData["NAME"] . " скоро начнется. Время начала в " . $arData["START"];
```

При выполнение curl в ответ пишет Bad Request

Если отправлять просто текстовую строку, без подстановки информации из массива arData, то все отправляет корректно

```
$textNotification = $dateStart . " Конференция скоро начнется. Время начала в ";
```

код отправки

```
$data_string = json_encode ($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  $curl = curl_init(TELEGRAM_BOT_URL);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
  // Принимаем в виде массива. (false - в виде объекта)
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
             'key: ' . TELEGRAM_BOT_KEY,
             'Content-Type: application/json',
             'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
  );
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
```

Если даже просто приравнять `$textNotification = $arData["NAME"]`, то тоже будет ошибка Bad Request.

В чем может быть проблема? В скрытых не поддерживаемых символах при передаче? Но я же просто одну строку приравнял к другой, откуда они могут появиться?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно или так

```
$textNotification = urlencode(" Конференция " . $arData["NAME"] . " скоро начнется. Время начала в " . $arData["START"]);
```

или так **curl_escape**

Comment: Если использую urlencode, то получаю Error: could not handle the request

Comment: Забыл указать, что перед json кодированием формирую массив `$data = [
  "id" => $id,
  "text" => $textNotification
  //"text" => urlencode($textNotification)
 ];`

Comment: @МихаилБарышев curl_escape

Comment: @МихаилБарышев а что не используйте постман

Comment: правильно ли я сформировал код при использовании curl_escape `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, curl_escape($curl, $data_string));` ? так как при его использовании Bad Request остается.

Comment: постман - это? можете ссылку скинуть где можно прочитать, не соображу, что имеется ввиду

Comment: @МихаилБарышев https://www.postman.com/

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен:
1) кодируем json без JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
2) добавляем к заголовку charset=utf-8

```
$data_string = json_encode ($data);
'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
```